# How get a product with a certain UnitPrice?(can I do this in a single request?)

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

### SOQl

```
[SELECT Name,Rating__c,(SELECT Product2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntries WHERE UnitPrice =: certainUnitPrice) FROM Product2 LIMIT 4]
```

It return all product with some empty UnitPrice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query doesn't quite match up with what you describe as your desired result.

Your query right now, put into words, sounds similar to what you're describing

> Find all product records, and give me the related pricebook entries that match this unit price

Instead of a including your inner query in the `SELECT` clause, you want to move it to be part of the `WHERE` clause (and make a minor change). Doing that will give you a query using what Salesforce calls a "Semi-join"

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Product 
WHERE Id IN 
   (SELECT Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE UnitPrice = :certainUnitPriceVariable)
```

The key difference with this "semi-join", other than the location of the sub-query, is that we're using the sub-query to filter the results for the outer query.

It's important that the two "sides" of the semi-join are working on the same type of data.

The left side of the semi-join is an `Id` for a `Product2` record.
The right side of the semi-join is whatever we put into the `SELECT` clause of the sub-query (in this case, `Product2Id`, also an `Id` for a `Product2` record).

If I'd describe that query using words, it'd be something like

> Find me all the products where there is a related pricebook entry that matches this unit price

Comment: One more thing I think worthy of note: You can't access the results of the sub-query in the results for the overall query. If you need to get at the `PricebookEntry` records too, then you'd need to have one sub-query in the `SELECT` clause to get access (in addition to the sub-query in the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: Thank you very much for a really detailed answer